# Is there a code of the Rosh in a single volume?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rabbeinu-asher

I am familiar of modern single volume editions of the codes of [Rambam](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=904) ([other](https://menuchapublishers.com/products/rambam-one-volume)) and [Alfasi](https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Saadia-Gaon/Rav-Alfas---Rabbi-Yitzchak-Alfasi-2-vol.__p-257-12540.aspx).

I have yet to come across such a volume of the Rosh. Has such such a volume been produced?

Comment: Prague 1628 (שפ"ח)? http://www.hebrewbooks.org/43204

Comment: Why are you interested in this?

Comment: @DoubleAA well, I already own the two prior codes, so, when I study tur or shulchan Aruch I can easily backtrack opinions and the like

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel where can I find single code volumes of the Rif & Rambam? Didn't know that existed!

Comment: Search for a volume called ‘Rav alfas’ and search for ‘chabad’s’ mishneh torah hashalem from ‘chazaq’ @alicht

Comment: You can also find single shulchan Aruch and Talmud

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel wasn't aware of any of that- thanks!

Comment: Can you provide links for alfasi in single volume, for Rambam too?

Comment: @kouty hope to edit them in at some point

Comment: Teshuvos ha-Rosh organized by order of Shas: https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=600254&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0